# RNFBMessagingModule.getToken got 4 arguments, expected 2 error. React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native

*I am getting error which is on title when i upgrade to latest versions of Firebase packages.*

[image]

**Error:**
[image]

*How can i handle this issue ?*
*any suggest ?*

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if my solution will work for you . I was facing similar issue.
I tried running `npx react-native-clean-project` but it was a temporary fix as the as release build not being generated.

After a few trial and errors. i reflected that react-native flipper was on and while i was upgrading the react native version

the solution was as you guessed removing react native flipper ,i have not only commmented the flipper from my prject but also removed `ReactNativeFlipper.java` file.

1. comment or remove flipper from app/build.gradle
2. comment or remove flipper from MainApplication.java
3. comment or remove ReactNativeFlipper.java

package versions in my project :

```
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.71.1",
"@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^16.5.1",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^16.5.1",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^16.5.1",
```

here is the link to read more about the [firebase-issue](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/6287)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the root cause of this issue is that the React version of the React Native project is not aligned with that of the React web app contained by the native app. The issue is fixed after updating React to 18 on both sides.